# How do we plot a list of HoloViews plots?

Tags: data-visualization, visualization, holoviews

I have a list of heatmaps

```
[:HeatMap   [column,row]   (analyte_value),
 :HeatMap   [column,row]   (analyte_value),
 :HeatMap   [column,row]   (analyte_value),
 :HeatMap   [column,row]   (analyte_value)]
```

Is there a command to render them all in the notebook, rather than:

(heatmaps[0] + heatmaps[1] + heatmaps[2] + heatmaps[3]).cols(1)

?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `+` and `*` operators are simply convenient ways of creating `Layout` and `Overlay` container objects respectively. To construct a `Layout` or `Overlay` from a list you can simply use the constructor directly, e.g. in your case that would simply be:

```
hv.Layout(heatmaps).cols(1)
```